# Как скомпилировать Java программу через командную строку?

Tags: java, cmd, javac

При попытке выполнить компиляцию кода через командную строку, выбрасывает ошибку "javac" не является внутренней или внешней командой, программой или исполняемым пакетом.
Пошуршал в интернете, нашел советы по решению и вот что я делаю:
Шаг 1:
Узнаю  адрес расположения файла 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_92\bin
Шаг 2:
Открываю Мой компьютер - Свойства - дополнительные параметры системы - переменные среды.
В системные среды забиваю новую ссылку под названием 
CLASSPATH и ссылкой C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_92\bin.
Шаг 3:
Перезагружаю компьютер.
После перезагрузки ничего не изменяется. 
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Во-первых, путь нужен не к JRE, а к JDK. Во-вторых, лучше установить 64-разрядный дистрибутив JDK, раз у вас 64-разрядная операционная система Наконец, путь `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin` надо добавлять в конец переменной окружения `PATH`, а `CLASSPATH` указывать не надо.

Comment: ОХ спасибо. Значит путь будет следующий C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\bin ???

Comment: Смотря какой JDK вы установили. Может быть и такой.